# Set Date to ASPxDateEdit in JS function

Tags: c#, javascript, devexpress

I am trying to set Date from Grid to ASPxDateEdit by using JS functions.

Grid got only GridViewDataTextColumn columns, and there is value with Date.

```
function UpdateValues() {
                clientListGrid.GetRowValues(clientListGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'chrono_;date_creation;', OnGetRowValues);

            }
            function OnGetRowValues(values) {
                clientLabelChrono.SetText(values[1]); // prints Wed Oct 26 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200
                clientLabelDate.SetDate = values[1];
            }
```

Q: I should use cast or something like that, because setting .Value .Date attribute is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clientLabelDate.SetDate is a function. You can find an answer in the [devexpress support site](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q250898)